# Append a New Table Row (1 Row 2 Columns) on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I'm trying to make an automation script that updates an existing Google Docs based on user responses from Google Form. so there are 3 questions (Name, University Number Identification or NIM in Bahasa, and Department or bidang), the department question used for categorizing each respondent.

So the goal is whenever a form is submitted, then the Docs is updated too. So I want to make the update make a new row with a cell that contains a template string that I already used in my script on the spreadsheets. But the problem is it only appends a single column for each row, however, that's not what I intended to have happened. I want it to update 1 row and 2 columns.

[Screenshot Of the Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9G1y.png)

[Screenshot of the Google Docs Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9YPz.png)

[Screenshot of what I intended the Google Docs when it's updated to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE5oB.png)

```
function appendTable(variabel){
      var rangePSDI = body.findText(variabel);
      var searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE, rangePSDI);
      element = searchElement.getElement();
      table = element.asTable();
      table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell(variabel);
  }

  if (bidang == 'PSDI') {
      body.replaceText('{{NamaPSDI}}', nama);
      body.replaceText('{{NIMPSDI}}', nim);
      appendTable("{{NamaPSDI}}");
      appendTable("{{NIMPSDI}}");
      return;
  } else if (bidang == 'PSDM') {
      body.replaceText('{{NamaPSDM}}', nama);
      body.replaceText('{{NIMPSDM}}', nim);
      appendTable("{{NamaPSDM}}");
      appendTable("{{NIMPSDM}}");
      return;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the [appendTableRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#detailed-documentation) as `<tr>` in HTML where you have to set the cell  using `<td>`or [appendTableCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#appendtablecell).

See [Table Row element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) in HTML.

Try this:

**Code:**

```
function appendTable(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('someid');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  var text = "PSDM";
  tables.forEach(table => {
    if(table.getCell(0,0).getText() == text){
      table.replaceText("{{Nama"+text+"}}", "test nama"+text)
      table.replaceText("{{NIM"+text+"}}", "test NIM"+text)
      var tr = table.appendTableRow();
      tr.appendTableCell("{{Nama"+text+"}}");
      tr.appendTableCell("{{NIM"+text+"}}");
    }
  })
}
```

### Before:

[image]

### After:

**PSDI**

[image]

**PSDM**
[image]

Comment: but what if i want to update the PSDM table? because currently i couldn't figure it out how to update a specific table

Comment: @TripleBritz - You can use body.getTables() and loop through it and check if the first cell in the table is PSDM or PSDI, from there we can determine which table to append the data. See my updated answer above.